# Display all register user in firebase except me

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I have a list of registered users in my firebase `users` node and I want to list all user and be able to chat with them. I want to skip my user data from the list of users that I will be fetching.

```
app.controller('ListAllUserCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
    $scope.currentUser = {};
    var usersRef  = new Firebase("https://bigzill.firebaseio.com/users");
    var usersRef2  = new Firebase("https://bigzill.firebaseio.com");
    var authData = usersRef.getAuth();

    if(authData) {
        usersRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                var user = snapshot.val();
                if(user.id != authData.uid ) {
                    $scope.users    = $firebaseArray(usersRef);
                    console.log(authData.uid);
                } else {
                    console.log("User not Authenticated ==== 2");
                }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("User not Authenticated");
    }
});
```

I don't really know how to do it.